# Debugging SSLSocket.startHandshake exception

Tags: java, ssl, exception

I have a java TLS based client/server applications I wrote 2-3 years ago and have been using almost daily since then on a number of different linux installations.  I don't do a lot of work in java -- writing this was really an exercise.

Anyway, it's never caused me grief since then, until yesterday, when all of a sudden I cannot authenticate with a server from a Fedora 31 box.  The cause was an update to openjdk the day before.  Other machines that have not had the update do not have the problem.  However, I tried rebuilding using Oracle JDK 13, and the problem is replicated.

Just to be clear:

- The server where the exception is thrown has **not** been updated.
- The only clients which now fail are ones connecting from the system which had the jdk update.
- Compiling the whole application and testing with a recent Oracle JDK has the problem -- clients cannot connect to servers. So this is something I have to fix or roll back the JRE and use that everywhere. >_<

Authentication is done using PKIX where there's a private CA backing the set of client and server certs, in pkcs12 files generated with `keytool`.  The `SSLContext` is initialized with a `TrustManagerFactor` and `KeyStore` more or less like this:

```java
KeyStore trusts;                                       
TrustManagerFactory tmf;                               
String trustPassword("abc123");                         

try (                                                  
    FileInputStream trustIn =                          
        new FileInputStream(new File("foobar.pkcs12")) 
) {                                                    
    tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");     
    trusts = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");           
    trusts.load(trustIn, trustPassword.toCharArray()); 
    tmf.init(trusts);                                  
}                                                      

SSLContext sscon = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");  
sscon.init (                                           
    someKeyManager,                                    
    tmf.getTrustManagers(),                            
    new SecureRandom()                                 
);
```

As mentioned, I am no java wizard.  However, I have done TLS network programming in other languages, so the concepts are pretty familiar.

The server socket is created:

```java
SSLServerSocket listenSock = sscon
    .getServerSocketFactory()
    .createServerSocket(port, backlog);
```

And a client connection:

```java
SSLSocket client = (SSLSocket)listenSock.accept(); 
SSLParameters sslp = new SSLParameters();       
sslp.setProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"}); 
client.setSSLParameters(sslp);              

try { client.startHandshake(); }
```

That `try` is where an exception is now thrown on the server, **"Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown"**.

A `jdb dump` of the exception:

```java
ex = {
    serialVersionUID: 4511006460650708967
    java.io.IOException.serialVersionUID: 7818375828146090155
    java.lang.Exception.serialVersionUID: -3387516993124229948
    java.lang.Throwable.serialVersionUID: -3042686055658047285
    java.lang.Throwable.backtrace: instance of java.lang.Object[5] (id=2005)
    java.lang.Throwable.detailMessage: "readHandshakeRecord"
    java.lang.Throwable.UNASSIGNED_STACK: instance of java.lang.StackTraceElement[0] (id=2007)
    java.lang.Throwable.cause: instance of java.net.SocketException(id=2008)
    java.lang.Throwable.stackTrace: instance of java.lang.StackTraceElement[0] (id=2007)
    java.lang.Throwable.depth: 5
    java.lang.Throwable.SUPPRESSED_SENTINEL: instance of java.util.Collections$EmptyList(id=2009)
    java.lang.Throwable.suppressedExceptions: instance of java.util.ArrayList(id=2010)
    java.lang.Throwable.NULL_CAUSE_MESSAGE: "Cannot suppress a null exception."
    java.lang.Throwable.SELF_SUPPRESSION_MESSAGE: "Self-suppression not permitted"
    java.lang.Throwable.CAUSE_CAPTION: "Caused by: "
    java.lang.Throwable.SUPPRESSED_CAPTION: "Suppressed: "
    java.lang.Throwable.EMPTY_THROWABLE_ARRAY: instance of java.lang.Throwable[0] (id=2015)
    java.lang.Throwable.$assertionsDisabled: true
}
```

None of which is helpful to me, meaning I don't understand it.

Where do I go from here?  The certs are fine, at least according to `keytool`, and as mentioned this code *had been running for years, accessed frequently* without problem.<sup>1</sup>  I have searched around about the specific error ("certificate unknown") but the results aren't very helpful -- the cert is there, the cert is not expired, the trust was loaded initially without qualm, etc.

---

1. This includes regenerating the PKIX stuff with `keytool` at regular intervals, as the certs are created with a limited lifespan.  The key pairs use 2048 bit RSA and `-sigalg SHA256withRSA`.

Comment: Are you sure the truststore is the same? And specifically that is has the CA certificate for the server certificate? Also, as an example, newer installations of OpenSSL for example in Debian have their default settings change so that certificates using keys of 1024bits or less, or using SHA1 for signatures, are just not allowed anymore. By updating some library, default settings like that may have changed. You may want also to compare the TLS handshake at the wire level from a working client and a non working one.

Comment: Will do -- although the key pairs use 2048 bit RSA (edited that in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can get some wonderful debug output during the handshake by using:

```
java --Djavax.net.debug=all ...
```

More about that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Since it was only a client system that had the problem post update, it makes sense that it was the client that was the one rejecting the connection.  And the reason:

```
TrustAnchor with subject "CN=myAuthority, C=CA"
does not have keyCertSign bit set in KeyUsage extension
```

Which, on inspection, it did not, which is a bit surprising because this was the cert used successfully to sign all the (otherwise working) client and server certs.  It's also a bit mysterious why this would matter when authenticating, but a little firmer security is not a bad thing.

The ultimate cause was in a script I've been using all this time to regenerate certs, and which was used to create the CA initially.  This is part of the parameters passed to `keytool` when creating the self-signed CA cert:

```
-ext KU=keyCertSign -ext KU=cRLSign
```

The cert did have the latter, meaning the previous value was replaced.  The correct way to do this is to list them together:

```
-ext KU=keyCertSign,cRLSign
```

Replacing the whole flawed at the root PKIX infrastructure wasn't too hard after all that.